# How to add two or three titles in one article ? How can I reorder the number of sections in each titles?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titles

I have an article which is including a lot of lessons I prepare for the class. For each lesson, I need to rename the title and recount the number of section from the beginning ?

Thi is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{QUI TẮC CỘNG - QUI TẮC NHÂN}
\maketitle
\section{Qui tắc cộng}
\section{Qui tắc nhân}

\title{CHỈNH HỢP - TỔ HỢP}
\section{Chỉnh hợp}
\section{Tổ hợp}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the setion in title "CHỈNH HỢP - TỔ HỢP" do not start at 1 but 4. I want to renumbering this section and the followings to 1. In addition, the tilte "CHỈNH HỢP - TỔ HỢP" is not at the same type of font and size compared to the title "QUI TẮC CỘNG - QUI TẮC NHÂN". How can I have two titles in just one document ?

Comment: Hi your question at the moment is not very clear. Can you show us a very short compilable document that shows the basic sectioning structure you currently have and a clearer description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi I have just edited my post to clarify my description.

Comment: It sounds like your document is not an “article” at all, but a “book” or “report”. Look into using a document class that supports chapters.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang That sounds like a reasonable answer. `report` is probably a sensible choice here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear  what you expect of `\title` but  usually that command do not should print nothing without `\maketitle`. And you usually you can use   `\maketitle` only once.

Probably what you really want is a book-like class as `scrbook`, with  chapters  and sections, not titles and sections.

Otherwise, this is near to what you have tried, but it need the `ltxdoc` class:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\title{aaaa}
\begin{document}
\title{AAAA}\date{}\maketitle
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}
\title{BBBB}\date{}\maketitle\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}
\end{document}
```

Or using `\part*` as fake titles. That could be used even in the `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{asdasd}
\part*{AAAA}
\section{aaaa}
\section{cccc}
\part*{BBBB}\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, is a bad idea, as you cannot have a table of contents of these "titles", although  this can be solved with little effort (e.g. `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{AAAA}`)